# Android: Saved video file cant be played

Tags: android-videoview, android-gallery

I have developed an app that can play videos from gallery and then save the played video back into a folder in gallery. The app is working fine as I can select and play videos from gallery and then save it. When the "Save Video' button is clicked, 'Video saved!' message pops and the saved video are found in gallery. The issue now is I cant play the video, it says 'Sorry, this video cannot be played'. Im unable to identify where it went wrong. My codings are as follow:

AndroidVideoPlayer.java:

```
public class AndroidVideoPlayer extends Activity {
/**
 * Called when the activity is first created.
 */
Button button, button2;
VideoView videoView;
private static final int PICK_FROM_GALLERY = 1;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_android_video_player);

    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.savevideo);
    videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoview);

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent intent = new Intent();

            intent.setType("video/*");
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);

            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Complete action using"), PICK_FROM_GALLERY);
        }
    });


    button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            savequesimage();
           // Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Sample Answer Saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();




        }


    });
 }

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode != RESULT_OK) return;

    if (requestCode == PICK_FROM_GALLERY) {
        Uri mVideoURI = data.getData();
        videoView.setVideoURI(mVideoURI);
        videoView.start();
    }

}


protected boolean savequesimage() {


    boolean success = false;
    View content = videoView;
    content.invalidate();
    // make the directory
    String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/SavedVideo/";
    File dir = new File(path);
    if(!dir.exists())
        dir.mkdirs();;
    // create unique identifier
    Random generator = new Random();
    int n = 100;
    n = generator.nextInt(n);
    // create file name
    String videoName = "Video_" + n + ".mp4";
    File fileVideo = new File(dir.getAbsolutePath(), videoName);

    try {
        fileVideo.createNewFile();
        success = true;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if (success) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Video saved!",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "Error during video saving", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    return true;

}

}
```

activity_android_video_player.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="- PLAY Video -"
    />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/savevideo"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="- Save Video -"
    />


<VideoView
    android:id="@+id/videoview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />


</LinearLayout>
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.mainapp.videoview" >
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".AndroidVideoPlayer"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Can anyone help me to resolve this issue? Any help/suggestion would be really helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, add permission READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE & WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE to AndroidManifest.xml like this:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

With Android Level >=23 you need ask permission in code:

```
// With Android Level >= 23 you need ask permission.
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {

    // Check if we have write & read permission 
    int writePermission = this.checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
    int readPermission = this.checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);

    if (writePermission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ||
            readPermission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // If don't have permission so prompt the user. 
        this.requestPermissions(
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                        Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                REQUEST_PERMISSION
        );
    }
}
```

See more here.